# VisualState Binding threading issue

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, multithreading

I have an audio recording app in Windows Phone 7. 
The app allows a user to play the recorded sounds.

I try to stick to MVVM guidelines where it is possible.

I have a play/stop button in a list of all recordings. Each recording has its own ViewModel, which, besides all, also controls the look of the corresponding play/stop button.

The button has a custom visual state defined in its' style.

The Visual State is bound to the ViewModel's property using the approach, shown here:
http://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/using-the-visualstatemanager-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern-in-wpf-or-silverlight/

Having implemented this approach, whenever I want to change the look of the play/stop button, I need to set the public string property (named "PlayStopVisualState") in my ViewModel to either "PlayingState" or "Normal", and that will assign an appropriate visual state to my button.

The problem is that when user presses the play button, a SoundEffectInstance is created in a background thread, which plays the sound. The thread then waits for the playing to end. When the recording playing is over (I have to track it in the same background thread, or create another for just tracking SoundEffectInstance.State) I set the PlayStopVisualState property back to "Normal", but I get a cross-thread reference exception. Isn't MVVM specifically designed to allow developers to manipulate logical variables in a view model, and not having to worry about how the changes to them are reflected in a View?

I know that I need to do the adjustment of the PlayStopVisualState property in a Dispatcher thread in order for the problem to disappear, but this is just no right. It, from my point of view, defeats the whole purpose of MVVM, leaving only the organizational advantage.

Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

UPDATE:
I have worked around the problem by using

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher
```

but it seems to me as a very "ugly" solution, given that I almost all over have MVVM pattern followed.

Comment: 'Each recording has its own ViewModel' shouldn't that rather be a Model?

Comment: It can be either way logically. For example a phone page would most likely have one view model and different models it relies to the UI. But when we have a view model for a control, each list item for example, can logically have own view model. Personally I don't see a misconception in that.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that's wrong, it seemed a bit strange, so I wondered if it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Dispatcher to reflect a UI-bound value is the correct way to do it, yes.

What you're forgetting is that your ViewModel is created on the UI thread. So any change to the ViewModel from a background thread, would a cross-thread operation.

You should consider if a background thread is really needed. , or if you could just schedule your action on the UI thread directly.

Comment: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` schedules the action on the UI thread. That's the whole idea with the dispatcher ;-)

Comment: Well, the problem is that you have to have an instance of that UI dispatcher. In my case I have no other way of locating it, other then Deployment.Current.Dispatcher. Is this a correct way to reference a UI thread dispatcher?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct way to access it from non-UI context, such as the ViewModel.